# How can I interrupt and stop a running function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have several buttons and each calculates some numbers and displays it on screen. Different buttons take differnet amount of time to finish calculation. In my current implementation, if I click on a button and then click on a different button before the first one finishes, the result from the second button is displayed only after the first one finishes. How can I modify this that as soon as I click the second button, it stops the calculation initiated by the first button and continues with its calculation?

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="One" onclick="displayNumber(1)">
<input type="button" value="Two" onclick="displayNumber(2)">
....
```

JavaScript

```
function displayNumber(id) {
    alert(calculateAwesomeNumber(id));
}
```

This may be not possbile in JavaScript as it is single-threaded and only one function can be running at any time. Am I correct?

Comment: try to use `setTimeout` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: could you post the code for calculateAwesomeNumner?

Comment: @lelloman, calculateAwesomeNumber is an arbitrary function I came up with. All I assume is that it takes different amount of time depending on its argument. For example, it could take really long for some numbers, but really short for some other numbers.

Comment: @Cherniv, Since I don't know how long each calculation exactly takes, using setTimeout is probably not going to work.

Comment: I asked for the code because maybe you can make a check inside the function to know if it has to go on or just return, in case the user pressed the second button

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [WebWorkers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html).

This will work in a separate thread and allow you to do heavy calculations without intefering with the UI thread.

You can signal the worker to stop.

See here for examples on how to use:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

If WebWorkers isn't an option you can use a flag to force the function to stop:

```
var _stop;

function displayNumber(num) {

    _stop = false;

    while(!_stop) {
        //calc
    }

}
```

And then on button2 click:

```
<input type="button" value="Two" onclick="_stop=true;displayNumber(2)">
```

Instead of a loop you can check `_stop` after each segment of the calculation is done.

Just note that if the calculation is long and busy you might not get a response of the button until it finishes. You can use `setTimout(..., 0)` from time to time inside the calculation  to allow other events to execute.

How you implement this will depend on the code you use for calculation.

You can break up the calculation for example like this:

```
function displayNumber(num) {

    var forCalculation;

    function step1() {
        //calc step 1 you have access to forCalculation and num vars here
        if (_stop) return;
        setTimeout(step2, 0);
    }

    function step2() {
        //calc step 2 you have access to forCalculation and num vars here
        if (_stop) return;
        setTimeout(step3, 0);
    }
    function step3() {
        //calc step 3 you have access to forCalculation and num vars here
        if (_stop) return;
    }
    step1();
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer although I didn't fully understand the second example. Why does the second `displayNumber` has only `step1()` in there? Who calls `step2()` and `step3()`?

Comment: @CookieMonster When step1 has gone through its part of the calculation the `setTimout` you see at the end of that section will call the step2. The setTimeout queues the event in the event queue so that the browser get a "breath" so-to-speak to handle f.ex. button clicks, re-paint etc. It makes it all more responsive. And the same with step2, when it has finished it calls step3. This way you can do heavy calculations and still get a responsive UI (if you don't want to use WebWorkers).

Comment: I understand it really well. Thank you for your time. I'll mark your answer as accepted and will give it a try.