# Kill a Javascript function or make Function Singleton

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to kill a running JavaScript function?

Or a way to ensure that only one copy of function will run at a time and on restart the previous invoke instance will be removed.

for example if I call

```
_.defer(heavyDutyPaint);  //How to kill this when a second one is called?
_.defer(heavyDutyPaint);
```

As of now I assign a token to the function call. Only with current value of token function can paint on screen.

something like following -

```
var token;

function heavyDutyPaint(){
     var localToken = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
     token = localToken;

     //perform a time consuming read
     var results = getResults();

     if(token === localToken){
          paintScreen(results);
     }
}

function defer(method){
    setTimeout(method, 1);
}

defer(heavyDutyPaint);
defer(heavyDutyPaint);
```

Is it the only way to ensure that only latest called one gets to access certain resources/services.

More Info - 
for the getResults method. It doest some REST calls, which wont happen more than once. There is a separate logic to manage that. The method does certain calculation though.
And i am not asking a Lock based solution as put in an answer. I am asking if there's a way to kill, stop execution. Or flag somehow. 
I actually want the second one to do its task not the first one. Consider these methods like filters. The latest requested filter is the useful one.

Comment: JavaScript code will run in the order you write it unless it's asynchronous. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, the second call to `heavyDutyPaint` won't run until the first call finishes. Is `getResults()` async? In that case, you want to use a callback, or promises.

Comment: @elclanrs valid point. I do meant async calls.

Comment: So `getResults` returns a promise?

Comment: not exactly. It results in several REST calls for the first time the method is run. for the second iteration onwards, if the data is present it will try to use that. But the method still performs some heavy calculation.

Comment: Are you using jQuery for the ajax call?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007482/how-can-i-interrupt-and-stop-a-running-function-in-javascript/17007680#17007680

Comment: @Ken thanks. I did search first, but this one did not came for me in results. Using webworkes should be work. Thanks. For me that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this:

```
function heavyDutyfunction = (function() {
  var lock = false;
  return function() {
    if(!lock) {
      lock = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // we do the work here
        lock = false;
      });
    }
  };
}());
heavyDutyFunction();
heavyDutyFunction(); // this call will like be passed over
```

this creates a `lock` var inside your heavy duty function scope, untouchable from the outside, and it prevents multiple calls from going through while a previous call is running. That said, a heavy duty function is typically more efficiently done through synchronous callbacks to free up the JS thread whenever possible.

Comment: thanks for answer mike. But it seems you got me a bit wrong. I am not looking for a way to prevent the second calls. I am looking for a way to stop the previous calls. kind of like a method which sorts and filters some huge dataset.

Comment: the mistake there is the idea of "sorting a huge dataset". Write the code to sort and filter a huge number of subsets, and make each subset sort a call that can be "not continued if necessary".

Comment: that indeed is a mistake. But sometimes even programmes have to abide by laws set by someone else. :(

Comment: Now we reach dangerous territory. Either you control the code for `heavyDutyFunction`, and then rewriting it is a great idea (even if only to turn it into a webworker that you can tell to do its job, and cancel with `worker.terminate()`, or chop up into an interruptible function chain), or you can't touch `heavyDutyFunction` and then we're done: when it runs, the JS thread will be in use until it's done and nothing can be called until then. So in this case you might *need* to advocate "this is not how JS works, this blocks the entire page process. It needs a rewrite".